# RUN wait until finish command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i tried convert and install package on debian, in dockerfile write

```
COPY oracle-instantclient-basiclite-21.1.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm /home/oracle-instantclient-basiclite-21.1.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm

RUN fakeroot alien --scripts /home/oracle-instantclient-basiclite-21.1.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm && dpkg -i /home/oracle-instantclient-basiclite_21.1.0.0.0-2_amd64.deb
```

when build, i got error

```
 => ERROR [7/9] RUN bash -c "fakeroot alien --scripts /home/oracle-instantclient-basiclite-21.1.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm && sleep 5 && dpkg -i /home/oracle-instantcli  86.1s
------
 > [7/9] RUN bash -c "fakeroot alien --scripts /home/oracle-instantclient-basiclite-21.1.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm && sleep 5 && dpkg -i /home/oracle-instantclient-basiclite_21.1.0.0.0-2_amd64.deb":
#11 79.31 oracle-instantclient-basiclite_21.1.0.0.0-2_amd64.deb generated
#11 84.85 dpkg: error: cannot access archive '/home/oracle-instantclient-basiclite_21.1.0.0.0-2_amd64.deb': No such file or directory
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -fakeroot alien --scripts /home/oracle-instantclient-basiclite-21.1.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm && sleep 5 && dpkg -i /home/oracle-instantclient-basiclite_21.1.0.0.0-2_amd64.deb]: exit code: 2
```

When i tried it via CLI, and run manual this command, all finish without error

I think maybe it was because dpkg did not wait until convert finish?

Comment: Could you try to put the image that your using, or put   a reproducible test scenario

Comment: The shell `&&` operator waits for the first thing to finish and checks that it was successful (exit status 0) before it does the second thing.  You shouldn't need the `sleep` or any sort of explicit waiting here.  (Nor do you need the explicit `bash -c` wrapper; Docker will automatically wrap `RUN` commands in a shell for you.)

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for idea, i add ls -la and found what alien unpack package to root / directory, i add WORKDIR /home and all ok now!